# Firefox Addons to go with Vimperator

Tags: firefox, browser-addons, vim, vimperator

Being a ViM fanatic, I recently discovered and began using the [Vimperator](http://vimperator.org/trac/wiki/Vimperator) addon for Mozilla Firefox.  I've really enjoyed using it so far, and there is even a list in the Vimperator wiki for [some addons](http://vimperator.org/trac/wiki/Vimperator/Wiki) that work well with Vimperator.  I'm curious as to what other addons that veteran Vimperator users would recommend?  Does anyone have any good favorites that blend in well with Vimperator?

Comment: Just want to add that that mapping (for opening gvim for textarea editing) is ctrl-i. Annoying that I need 50 rep. to comment on posts.

Answer (score 8):

If you use google bookmarks as online bookmarks storage service then [gmarks](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/2888) is fundamental. 
With the following mapping in your `.vimperatorrc` file:

```
map gb :emenu GMarks.Add/Edit Bookmark<CR>
```

pressing `gb` opens the add/edit bookmark dialog of the gmarks addon, where you can set the title, labels and notes of the bookmark.

The **`:emenu`** command can be used to quickly access **any other firefox menu entry**, included any addon menu entry. So many addons could 'blend well' with vimperator.

---

Another vimperator suggestion is to learn how to setup and use [search engine plugins](http://mycroft.mozdev.org/) that become very powerful using vimperator. For example I set-up two plugins for translating from italian to english and from english to italian (taken from [wordreference.com](http://wordreference.com/)) and gave them respectively the keywords `iten, enit`.

Now I can quickly search for the translation of the world 'paonazzo' using:

```
:open iten paonazzo
```

Exploiting this vimperator feature you can easily set for example a keywork `su` to quickly search superuser.com using the [superuser search engine plugin](http://mycroft.mozdev.org/search-engines.html?name=superuser) and searching for 'vimperator' using:

```
:tabopen su vimperator
```

The keywords associated to search engines can be defined from:

```
:dialog searchengines
```

Answer (score 6):

I like the [It's All Text!](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/4125) addon which allows you to use any text editor (Vim works great) to edit text on forms, instead of the anemic little `<textarea>` editor that the browser offers by default.

Comment: Like other people said, you really don't need `It's All Text!` whith `vimperator`. Just press `<Ctrl-i>` when the focus is on a textarea and `vimperator` will open `gvim`. See `:help i_<C-i>` and `:help editor`.

Answer (score 2):

**TreeStyleTab** or **Tab-Kit**, which both move your tabs from the top to the left side and display them in a tree-like structure.

You don't need extensions like It's All Text! Vimperator already provides  mapping (when textarea is focused) which launches gvim.

Answer (score 2):

My favorite plugin is probably maine_coon.js. It hides the command line when you are not using it so you get even more real estate!

Another good plugin is scrollposition.js. It adds horizontal position to the status bar along with the vertical position. I use vimperator with no scroll bars, this helps to let me know when there is something more to the page. You can find this one as an attachment to issue #32 in the vimperator issue tracker (I can't link it with only 1 rep point)

There is a nice plugin helper called pluginManager.js. It can show you more information about the plugins you have installed and help you administer the plugins themselves.

Last but not least is bitly.js. This gives you a quick way to shorten and add to the clipboard the current url you are on (using the `:bitly` command).

I don't have 10 rep points yet, so i couldn't link all of these like I wanted to. Most of them can be found here: http://svn.coderepos.org/share/lang/javascript/vimperator-plugins

Answer (score 1):

Good links. maine_coon.js is excellent, as is pluginManager.js.

You might be interested in an enhancement I made to the scrollposition.js plug in.

I made it show what percentage of the document is actually visible, in addition to how much it has been scrolled.

That way you get the information that you would otherwise get from the size of the scroll bar button.

You can find the link on the issue page you talked about above: http://code.google.com/p/vimperator-labs/issues/detail?id=32

Also, +1 for Tab-Kit, very nice functionality. You can autohide your list of tabs and then that gives you even more screen real estate.

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to add that BarTab is really handy if you are addicted to tabs. It stops all of your tabs from loading at startup and can unload tabs from memory while firefox is running.

Answer (score 1):

Actually so much is possible with Javascript, you could mimic many addon functionality (without the need for a UI) with Vimperator!

But here are few Firefox addons that I find usefull:

- *Cycle Collector Analyzer, Preferences Monitor, Open in Browser, TableTools2, keyconfig, NoScript* and *Private Tab*
- also try using the *Tile Tabs* addon with something like:

```
  mappings.addUserMap(
    [modes.NORMAL], [""], "tile tabs vertically",
    function() {tileTabs.menuActions('new-2vert',null);}
    );
```

- as a student, 24 key mappings are invaluable for handeling bibliography with:
  *Zotero, Zotero Better Bib(La)Tex, Zutilo Utility for Zotero*
  (just re-write Will Shank's mappings for Zotero and Zutilo with Pentadactyl)

I would like to have advanced control over MIME types though... (like change download action per-url and per-filetype, ref. *Automatic Save Folder*

Answer (score 0):

[NoScript integration plugin](http://vimperator.org/trac/ticket/1) is a must.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to use It's all text! instead of the builtin option. You can set a hot key in It's all text!, I set mine to `ctrl + e`. This won't be all that helpful since you can't use it directly (you'd have to `ctrl + v and then ctrl + e`). So I overrode the deafult `ctrl + i` with the following in my `.vimperatorrc`

```
" Use It's all text instead of the built-in command
inoremap <C-i> <C-v><C-e>
```

Now when you are in a `<textarea>` you can launch It's all text! with `ctrl + i` as you normally would.

Comment: I am curious about the reasons why you prefer using It'all text! instead of vimperator builtin. Maybe you tried both and know the differences?

Comment: I didn't like the way that the builtin option interacted with MacVim. I haven't tried it in a while (or since switching to pentadactyl). Might be time to give it another shot.